# How can I convert mp3 to speex?

Tags: software-recommendation, sound, mp3

What is a good way to convert mp3 files to speex files? I'll favor answers that give an easy solution for converting multiple files at a time and/or maintain good quality for spoken audio. Though any solution will be appreciated since I haven't found even a difficult way that works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example for processing all mp3 files in current folder to speex using wide band (input rate converted to 16KHz with best SRC available - SoX):

```
for f in *.mp3 ; do sox "$f" -r 16k -t wav - | speexenc -w - "${f%.*}.speex" ; done
```

Depending on preferences change speex option and/or SoX rate converter to appropriate setting. For spoken audio example wide band should be fine

Comment: I also needed to install sox (obvious) and also libsox-fmt-all (not so obvious). Though libsox-fmt-mp3 would probably have covered it in this case.

Comment: Yes, I presumed that SoX is present, like anywhere someone is doing something with audio, other than listening. I don't know what's the purpose of your task, but you may be interested also in OPUS (former Celt) by known developers: http://celt-codec.org/ Listening tests outperformed everything available (Vorbis aoTuV, Apple HE AAC, ...) http://people.xiph.org/~greg/opus/ha2011/ although bitstream is not frozen yet, it's generally available to public

Comment: It should be noted that the speex files produced by this command line will retain none of the metadata from the mp3 files.

Answer (score 2):

You can use ffmpeg:

```
lame filename.mp3 filename.wav
ffmpeg -i  filename.wav filename.spx
```

Source: http://paramitech.com/convert-speex-file-into-mp3/

Answer (score 1):

Although Opus is a better option these days you can use FFmpeg (if configured with *--enable-speex*):

```
for f in *.mp3
  do 
  ffmpeg -i "$f" -ar 32000 -q:a 10 "${f%.mp3}.spx"
done
```

This produced quite reasonable audio on my setup....